# Can't get a decimal when using functions?

Tags: c, function, decimal

So I was practicing using functions and ran into a problem. I made a program that divides two numbers that the user enters, but I used a function to write it. Now, when I use a function, the final answer I get is not a decimal number, even though I am using a double data type. When I write the program without using a function, I don't have any problems, but as soon as I use a function I can't get a decimal number. I would be very grateful if anyone could help me! Thanks!

Here's the code:

```
double divide(num1,num2)
{
    double result;
    result = num1/num2;
    return result;
}

int main ()
{
    double num1;
    double num2;

    printf("Enter the first number: ");
    scanf("%lf", &num1);
    printf("Enter the second number: ");
    scanf("%lf", &num2);

    printf("The answer is: %lf", divide(num1,num2));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try specifying the parameter types: `double divide(num1,num2)` -> `double divide(double num1, double num2)`

Comment: "as soon as I use a function I can't get a decimal number. " --> always a good idea to include a sample of values used, the output seen and output expected.

Comment: Thanks, the issue is resolved now! I am using Xcode btw. I had a yellow warning with the previous function I used saying 'This old-style function definition is not preceded by a prototype'. Now it's gone though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare your function, you need to specify a type, or the default is `int`:
Your `double divide(num1,num2)` is read as `double divide(int num1,int num2)` - but you want `double divide(double num1,double num2)`

Comment: "default is int" --> I would not expect that since C99 - it is an error. And C99 or later is being used given `"%lf"` in the `printf()`. Hmmm.

Comment: Agreed. But obviously he didn't get a compilation error, so I assume his compiler has non-standard 'enhancements'.

Answer (score 2):

If you try to compile with `-Wall`, you should hopefully get an error saying

> `warning: type of 'num1' defaults to 'int'`

Change to `double divide(double num1, double num2)`